# Defining primary key in spark JDBC write

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, primary-key

I have a requirement to set a particular column as primary key while writing a dataframe from pyspark to sql using jdbc.
Tried using the function 'createTableColumnTypes'

```
# Calling the action and writing the results to SQL DB
result.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option('createTableColumnTypes', 'KEY_IDENTIFER_COLUMN VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY') \
    .option("dbtable","test") \
    .option("user", db_username) \
    .option("password", db_password) \
    .save()
```

It fails with an error. Any solutions on how this can be done?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found some solution ?

Comment: Yes, I created a SQL procedure to define primary key of the table. And called that procedure from data bricks. This will work perfectly